# Is there a way of telling whether GUICtrlCreateInput has text in it?

Tags: string, user-interface, input, autoit

I am writing a GUI in AUTOIT that has a lot of GUICtrlCreateInputs.
Is there a way to tell if the user has entered text into a "GUICtrlCreateInput"

I tried the StringCompare and StringLen functions but they didn't help.

I "StringCompare"ed with ""

StringLen returned 9 and sometimes 10 in cases where I hadn't typed anything into the inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
If StringStripWS(GUICtrlRead($inputCtrl), 8)  "" Then
       ; do something
EndIf
```

Comment: Thank you for suggesting that function and flag, I didn't realize it existed. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to accomplish what I wanted but I'll mark your answer as best.